# Looking for bijective function for unsigned integers, mapping sequences 0,..,n uniformly onto image

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, integer

I'm trying to find a (hash) function, that takes an unsigned integer with either 32 or 64 bit and maps it onto the same type again.

It should be bijective and fast.

Additional property:

For any n the sequence of ints 0 to n should be mapped "uniformly" onto the image.
Meaning, if I split the image into k equally large subsets, they should be roughly equal, for k << n.

Answer (score 0):

This meets all of your requirements:

```
unsigned int identity(unsigned int x) {
    return x;
}
```

Comment: no, it doesn't. The first N integers are of course in the first N integers, so your k partitions are totally unevenly used.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to find a (hash) function, that takes an unsigned integer with either 32 or 64 bit and maps it onto the same type again.
>
> It should be bijective and fast.

Um, the function that satisfies that with 0 collisions is the identity function, ie.

```
uint64_t hash(uint64_t inp) {
    return inp;
}
```

Your additional properties:

> For any n the sequence of ints 0 to n should be mapped "uniformly" onto the image.

Hm, so identity doesn't do it, because the first n numbers will of course be compact. However:

Bit-reversal does the trick!

So instead of returning the same numbers, just return the bit-reversed version of them.

Bit reversal is *usually* not a fast operation, unless you've got tricks and/or CPU instructions that help you with that.

EDIT: Ah wait, I remember Knuth has proposed a function for that which should be much faster than your average hash impl.

Comment: Reversing the bits should be equal to:f(x) = 2^32 -1 - x ? But that doesn't yield a uniform distribution over the integer range?

Comment: @hatero Marcus means to reverse the order of the bits rather than toggle the bits. `0b11001001` -> `0b10010011` (this is an 8-bit example, rather than 32- or 64- of course).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `mult` is odd (and the range of `T` is a power of 2, as it would be on any modern processor), any function returned by

```
template <T>
auto linear_congruential_hash(T mult, T incr) {
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value,
                  "template argument must be an integral type");
    return [mult, incr](T n) -> T {
        return mult * n + incr;
    }
}
```

is bijective.  And if `mult` is close to the upper limit of `T` then the function will be close to satisfying your uniformity requirement also (just avoid taking `mult` such that some small multiple of it is too close to 0, e.g. `0x7fffffffU` would be bad).  So, just to give a concrete example, something like `linear_congruential_hash<uint32_t>(0x68832099U, 0x30571005U)` should hopefully work well.

Comment: I think you also need to assert that `T` is unsigned otherwise you have undefined behavior.